# Using settings in dll?

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, settings

I am writing a library to control measurement instruments and make calibrations. The library will be used in a few apps.

At one point I need to set the max. permitted signal's deviance, which depends on the transmitter being calibrated. So for. ex. Tansmitter-typ 1 has .2% and typ 2 has .1% and typ 3 has .05%.

```
 Private Function GetMaxDeviationAllowed(transmitterName as String) As Double
        With transmitterName.Substring(0, 8)
            If .Contains("050") Then
                Return 0.2 
            ElseIf .Contains("100") Or .Contains("101") then
                Return  0.15 
            ElseIf .Contains("200") or .Contains("201") then
                Return  0.05 
            ElseIf .Contains("_PSP") 
                Return  0.2
            Else
                Return 0.2 'ASK: Use default tolerance or throw TypeNotSupported exception?'
            End If
        End With
End Function
```

This programm will be used by people without any programming-knowledge and I wanted to give them the possibility to change the max. permitted deviance of each transmitter type without changing source code.

I always read that is no good idea using settings in the library and thats is better letting the UI handle the settings, but I can't (at least I dont know how) wrap such a method, because If I have 100 diferent types I need a method with 100 parameters (one for each type, if each has a different maxDeviationPermitted). 
Also if I use a setting file with the dll, afaik this will not be used and also not be copied to the app output directory...so I am a little bit lost here...

Maybe I am just short-minded but if not would be nice if someone can give me some hint here.

Thank you in advance
RG

Comment: A library is used by programmers. Settings are used by end-users. Since this is a library, put your settings in variables and provide methods for those using the library to change them. I'm not sure what you mean by "100 different type". I only see one type, a double (decimal number).

Comment: You dont need 100 parameters.  Create a class to hold the config values and pass that.  The app can create it and set the values accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. With 100 diff. types I mean transmitter types. If you could give a quick example of what you mean will be great. But if I understood right, you mean for ex. create a module "MaxAllowedDeviationByType" with variables/properties like Type1=0.2, giving the end user  the option to change? Is there a way to make changes (if made) permanently?

Comment: If you intend for this to be a library, then yes, you will need a setting for each transmitter type. Libraries are tools used by programmers. The end user will never use a library. End users use programs. Programs use libraries. Actually, I will go ahead and write you an answer detailing a possibly better design.

Comment: I appreciate it @Clay07g. I write code since a year (very intensive) and I notice now with my first bigger projects that I need to improve my app-design and code-organization knowledge

Comment: I added an answer, but I can't be sure it fits to your situation because I don't know the overall functions of your library. Just understand that you don't need a parameter for each transmitter type. Maximum deviation is a single value. Just pass a deviation to your calculation methods. Your calculation methods don't care if the maximum deviation matches the transmitter type. That should be handled in your main program. If you want, give me another method you want to put into your library and I can suggest a good design for it in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your high-level design is a bit flawed. So let's break down some of the components.

**What is a Library?**

A Library is a set of (usually) precompiled functions that can be used by multiple programs. Libraries are simply tools. For example, in your code, you use a "String" and call its "Substring" method. That's a library! It performs tasks for you. Notice that you can only change the behavior of that method by giving it a different string with different parameters. Libraries don't change. They don't have settings.

**So should you make a Deviation Parameter for each Transmitter Type?**

This is a solution. It would allow you to change the deviations from each of your programs.

But then you would need to create a variable for every single transmitter type, then make a public method to change it. That way your library knows what deviations to use. You would have to set these every single time you reference the library, in every one of your programs.

In short, this is too much work. Libraries are meant to be as flexible as possible.

**Any other ideas?**

I'm not sure what your library does. I see it has a method to "Get the max deviation". I assume this value is then used in other methods?

So let's say this is your method:

```
Private Function MakeCalibration(transmitterName as String)

    Dim deviation as Double = GetMaxDeviationAllowed(transmitterName)
    // Do more stuff

End Function
```

Pretty simple, but it has too much dependence on that "GetMaxDeviationAllowed" method. This method cannot work unless another method works. That is improper design.

Here is something better:

```
Private Function MakeCalibration(transmitterName as String, maxDeviationAllowed as Double)

    // Do more stuff using "maxDeviationAllowed"

End Function
```

This allows your method to be used with anything.

This solution may not be exactly what you need, because I don't know what your goal is. However, the point is that **your library should NOT care about what a given transmitter's maximum deviation is**. All your library should do is take a transmitter type and a deviation, and perform what it needs to perform.

Maximum deviation should be decided **in your program that's used by end-users**. Then you can use a setting file, a setting's window, a JSON config, an XML config, a SQL server, or whatever you want. Your library doesn't care.

**Helpful Articles for design**

- http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/07/single-responsibility-prinicple/

Comment: Thank you very much for the long answer. I notice I forget often the very basics....keep things simple and independent. I think my problem is trying to   write the master method. Also spliting responsabilities between library and UI is another topic I should work on.....if you have some info-link or article for me would be really great :) Thanks again

Comment: No problem. Sorry I couldn't give you more code examples. I don't really know VB.net. I do c# mainly, but I love design challenges. Good luck with your project!